# Automatically change map key based on debug or release version

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Sometimes I forget to change over from my debug Google map key when I compile my app. Is there a way to have it change automatically so that I don't have to manually change it in the manifest everytime and possibly forget to change it for the release build again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do it not to have to change it at all.

First of all, you can check in the API_KEY into your repository even if it is public. Nobody can use the key without having your debug or release keystore (and passwords).

Secondly, you can assign a single API key multiple SHA-1;package pairs in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

Comment: It's the secondly answer.