# Google maps v2 android api key working only with debug key

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, sha1, android-maps-v2

I have a problem with Google Maps api v2 on my android app.

I have generated the key for the debug certificate and everything works fine, but I can't make it work with the release certificate.

I've generated the key and the alias with eclipse, then I took the SHA1 which eclipse shows at the end of the "Export signed application" process.

Then I generated the api key for android apps in my google api console using
SHA1;package name

But it doesn't work... it works only with the debug key generated in the same way, only using the sha1 of the debug certificate!

Please help me, otherwise I can't release my app

Comment: give it a few hours maybe

Comment: yup.. give it some time

Comment: It can sometimes take a couple of hours for the changes you've made in to the Google API console to propogate fully. Give it a couple of hours and try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424539/automatically-change-map-key-based-on-debug-or-release-version/18427417#18427417

Comment: which OS have you work ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file, I guess you've forgotten to set your release map api key there while exporting with your release key?

Answer (score 1):

Me too faced the same problem during releasing my app to google Play, when I used Google Maps V2 in my app. After succeeding the issue, I wrote a blog post regarding this you can have a [look](http://smdaudhilbe.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/how-to-create-release-keystore-digitally-sign-publish-android-app-to-google-play-android-market/).

As everyone requested, I would say the answer in following steps
1) Sign up your app using eclipse adt
2) Note down the SHA1 finger print which will be displayed at console of your eclipse adt
3) Again go to google console and get API_KEY for your app by using above got SHA1 fingerprint
4) Replace the old API_KEY with the new API_KEY on to manifest.xml of your app
5) Again sign up your app. Your app is ready to be published. But keep in mind that once you published your app to google market, you should be able to release updates to your app by signing **.apk** using the keystore which you used earlier for release.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: You should always post the essential content of the link you're providing here! Please edit your answer so that someone looking at it can gather what the solution is without *having* to follow a link (which might go down in future)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two files google maps api.xml, one is the debug and release the other, then you should replace the key generated on google website console and enter this file, another outlet is inserted directly into the manifest.